# FacebookSDK Samples Example not working on Android phone

Tags: java, android, facebook-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

Whether its me or my cell phone or my Facebook account problem. I downloaded Faecbook SDK today. Thought I will be running few sample apps today from the examples folder. I tried running `SessionLoginSample` example and `Scrumptious example` in the emulator. Both are working fine there. I am able to login using Facebook and moving to other intent as well.

But as soon as I installed the app on my Android phone (S3). None of the application works on my phone. I get a Facebook login screen on my cell phone, after logging in successfully by providing my username and password, I always get Facebook has stopped working. And then I get `Scrumptious` app has forced closed. I haven't made any changes in the code.

And after sometime I get exception on my console as-

```
01-30 11:06:08.400: E/AndroidRuntime(7463): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Does anyone also has faced similar problem? If yes, can anyone help me out here? And is there any way I can post this problem to Facebook developer site as well?

**Note:-** Is there anything I need to change in the code or some keys before installing the application on the my Android Phone? I am not sure of that. If it is working in an emulator it should work on the Android Phone as well. Right?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is related to an already known bug of the Android SDK.
I suggest to turn off the **Don't keep activities** option in the *Developer Options* of your device *Settings*. In my case it helped me to resolve the issue.

You can find more info about the bug on this [page](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/517427168282297).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.